# Updating table images using for loop

Tags: php, mysql

hi i am trying to update images using for loop as i used while inserting them. but it is just updating one values on all records. please

```
<?php session_start();
require_once("SubmitController/sale_property_controller.php");
$objproperty = new sale_property_controller();

if (count($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 0) {
    //Loop through each file
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
        //Get the temp file path
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
        //Make sure we have a filepath
        if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
            //save the filename
            $shortname = date('d-m-Y-H-i-s') . '-' . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
            //save the url and the file
            $filePath = "../img/saleproperty/" . $shortname;
            //Upload the file into the temp dir
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {
                $_SESSION['Property_images'][] = $shortname;
            }
        }
    }
}
if(!$_SESSION['Property_images']){}else{
    foreach ($_SESSION['Property_images'] as $items => &$item ) {
        $property_id=$_GET['id'];
        $objproperty->Updateproimg($property_id, $item);
        }
}
?>
```

this is my function

```
function Updateproimg($property_id, $item)
{   

    $sql="update images_property set images='".$item."' where property_id='".$property_id."' ";

    $this->update($sql);
}
```

Comment: See how a bit of sensible code indentation make the code readable

Comment: Thats because your query will update all `images_property` rows with the `property_id` you pass each time it runs. I bet they all end up with the LAST shortname

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes. can you help with any other solution.

Comment: I think I would have expected that to be an INSERT as well as you are adding images

Comment: _can you help with any other solution_ not without knowing a lot more about your app and the database

Answer (score 0):

I feel you have to take count on count($_FILES['upload']) instead of $_FILES['upload']['name'];

```
$count = count($_FILES['upload'])

for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++) {
     $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload'][$i]['tmp_name'];
}
```

Are you trying multiple file upload?